# Access denied finding property ro.vendor.hwui.texture_cache_size

Tags: android, performance, caching, opengl-es, android-9.0-pie

While launching activity I am getting this error,

```
Access denied finding property ro.vendor.hwui.texture_cache_size
```

Everything was working properly till Android OREO but not working in android Pie.

Additionally, I have observed this issue on Coolpad cool 3 phones not in other Android Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time and research, I got to know that the device mentioned above Coolpad cool 3 is having an issue in it,
I tried many solutions but I was not able to resolve the issue,
Finally, I tried other installed applications AND the result was the same, the same issue coming for all applications.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but recently I had that same problem and I solved it writing this in the manifest.xml:

```
<application
...
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...>
</application>
```

You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted

Basically, what you are doing is allowing unsafe http connections.