# What this Error "ro.vendor.pref_scale_resolution"?

Tags: java, android

My application run properly but this error is again again show any find this answer please help

**provide your best answer**

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.pref_scale_resolution"
```

Comment: Appears to be a cache permission problem? Could be a missing resource file.
This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495323/access-denied-finding-property-ro-vendor-hwui-texture-cache-size

Comment: try this solution but again error show

Comment: What is the device? Did you try it on another device?

Comment: I try virtual device the error was not show